# Increase limit when using fputcsv

Tags: php, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I recently asked a question about this, but think after 2 days of troubleshooting I have a better question to ask.

Using fputcsv works great until the file is 4KB or bigger.  How can I increase this limit?  I have tested the following:

```
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
```

and I see the changes being reflected in phpinfo, however apparently none of these are related to the issue.

Any other ideas what global settings might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some other things to consider

```
 upload_tmp_dir
```

The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload.

```
 post_max_size
```

Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload

```
 file_uploads
```

Whether or not to allow HTTP file uploads.